# Is there a token for capture line breaks in multiline regex?

Tags: php, regex, multiline, pcre

I've run into this problems several times before when trying to do some html scraping with php and the preg* functions.

Most of the time I've to capture structures like that:

```
<!-- comment -->
<tag1>lorem ipsum</tag>

<p>just more text with several html tags in it, sometimes CDATA encapsulated…</p>
<!-- /comment -->
```

In particular I want something like this:

```
/<tag1>(.*?)<\/tag1>\n\n<p>(.*?)<\/p>/mi
```

but the **\n\n** doesn't look like it would work.

Is there a general line-break switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could replace the `\n\n` with `(\r?\n){2}` this way you capture the `CRLF` pair instead of just the `LF` char.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to parse HTML using regexps ? HTML isn't regular and there are too many corner cases.

I would investigate some form of HTML parser (perhaps [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) ?), and then identify the pattern you're interested in via the returned HTML data structure.

Comment: Scraping using regex worked fine for me as of today. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could look at the [Dom Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to php.  It has a function to [load html from a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) [or a file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).  You can then use the php dom methods to traverse the dom and find the data you are interested in.